# Share FROM TikTok into my app - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, share-extension, tiktok-api, react-native-share

I'm trying to share from TikTok into my react native app using react-native-receive-sharing-intent. This library only gets the url of the TikTok video. I've read through the [TikTok video share API](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/share-kit-ios-quickstart-v2/), and I do not understand how Instagram and Snapchat is able to get the actual TikTok video downloaded and shared into the app. According to the TikTok for Developers, the sharing only allows into the TikTok, not from TikTok to another app.

Here is an example [video](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/1at7eon/share_from_tiktok_into_my_application/) that is between TikTok and Instagram.

Do companies like Instagram and Snapchat have some sort of private, corporate relationship where they get private share apis from TikTok and vice versa?

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out, but I'm getting inconsistent results. You can use `https://www.tiktok.com/oembed?url=...` however this will only work for a "full" TikTok link (e.g. https://www.tiktok.com/@chiefgreenscreens/video/7330327748378004782). If I take a "share link" (which seems to be shortened, e.g. https://vm.tiktok.com/ZGeyRxXE2/) and pass it to /oembed I get a 400. Sometimes I'm able to use `curl` to get the expanded link but from within the app this always fails, returning 200 + garbage html instead of 301/2 + expanded link.

Comment: @DavidCarboni I was able to circumvent this share url issue by using a WebView and loading the url. Then the `onNavigationStateChanged` prop produces the new url that it transforms into so you can get the original url and not the unique share url. My oEmbed works reliably since doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question and in line with Martin JK's answer, it would appear that TikTok does have private relationships with the big social media platforms via a supposed TikTok partner program. See response from TikTok for Developers.

[image: ScreenshotFromEmail]

Comment: I've just had a look in the app and although the share menu is a custom one with only TikTok's options (which sounds like what this message is referring to) there is a (...) More option on both iOS and Android that gets you to the standard share sheet.

Comment: @DavidCarboni That's correct, and you can get the URL from that extra (...) menu. The thing is though the the custom share menu that TikTok uses actually provides the raw TikTok video that you could potentially interact with. If you share from TikTok into snapchat via the custom menu. You will see that there is a a loading animation and it actually feeds snapchat the raw video. This is what I'm looking for for my application.

Comment: Ah yes that makes perfect sense. I've been able to get my app onto the share sheet but as you say, it only receives the shortened link and I've not found a way to expand that. Seems like that's what we're all looking for

Answer (score 1):

The integration between different apps often involves a combination of public APIs, private partnerships, and possibly reverse engineering. While TikTok's official APIs might not provide direct access to download and share videos outside of its platform, larger companies like Instagram and [Snapchat](https://snapchatplanet.com/) might have established private partnerships or agreements with TikTok to enable seamless sharing between their platforms.